# Laravel Elixir : Create an object of a javascript class defined in another javascript file

Tags: webpack, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, laravel-elixir

I'm using laravel 5.3 and vuejs. I have defined a javascript class named 'Form' inside a js file named form.js and I want to create an object of this class in app.js file. I have added both js files in webpack and I have also required the 'form.js' file inside the app.js. But I get the following error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Form is not defined ...
```

Here is my app.js code :

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./form.js');

formElm = document.getElementById('form');

new Vue({
    el: "#form",
    data: {
        form: new Form(formElm)
    },
    methods: {
        ....
    }
});
```

And here is my form.js code :

```
class Form {
    constructor(formElm) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

And this is how I've added the js files in gulpfile.js :

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack(['app.js', 'form.js'], 'public/js/app.js');
});
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to export it in order to use it. In your Form class:
`module.exports=Form` or if you use the es6 import syntax `export default Form`

In your app js `var Form = require('./form.js')` should make it work